# how to send information from wxPython thread to a twisted thread

Tags: python, multithreading, client, twisted

I have a problem that I cannot seem to solve.  This problem has to do with a wxPython/twisted application that I am building.  This application preforms the following functions.  This application starts a gui wxPython window and when the user clicks the button. Then a new thread is started that connects to a Twisted TCP server over ssl.  This connection is constant and will stay connected while the user is running the GUI.  Any data that is sent from the sever to the gui client shows up in the gui useing wx.lib.pubsub. The items that I have describe work fine.

My Problem:
I have this wxPython combo box that gets populated from data sent to the client from the server that it is connected to.  I have an event that when something is selected in the combo box, that information (selection) should then be sent to the server.  I have no idea how to do this.  What I mean is I have the selected value from the combobox (self.combo_box_1.GetValue()) but do not know how to send that information into the twisted reactor that is running in a different thread.  This is killing me. I have search on how to do it but do not understand how to make it work with a constant running socket in a different thread.  Any help/examples would be so very welcomed.

Here is the code that I am using

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs 
import gettext
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import ssl, reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory, Protocol
import time
from Service_Encode_Decode import encode_decode
from threading import Thread

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class EchoClient(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Sending inital hello request"
        ed = encode_decode()
        to_send = ed.encode("hello",1,["client"])
        # Sending a callback signal to the GUI
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'action', arg1=to_send, arg2="NULL")
        self.transport.write(to_send)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        ed = encode_decode()
        status,count,item = ed.decode(data)
        # Need to see what is contained in the message by seeing what status is
        if status == "url":
            print "Status is %s...Count is %s... Full message is %s" % (status,str(count),data)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage,'sendRequest',arg1=self.sendAccessRequest)
            # Calling the pub.SendMessage event to alert the listener and take the information
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'update_url', arg1=item)
        elif status == 'hello' and item == 'server':
            to_send = ed.encode("ping",1,['client'])
            self.transport.write(to_send)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage,'sendRequest',arg1=self.sendAccessRequest)
        time.sleep( 2 )

    def sendAccessRequest(self,request):
        ed = encode_decode()
        rtn = ed.encode('service','1',request)
        self.transport.write(rtn)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class CtxFactory(ssl.ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self):
        self.method = SSL.SSLv23_METHOD
        ctx = ssl.ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)
        ctx.use_certificate_file('./cert.pem')
        ctx.use_privatekey_file('./key.pem')
        return ctx
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.frame_1_statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(1, 0)
        self.combo_box_1 = wx.ComboBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[], style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.combo_box_1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.item_selected)
        self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("button_1"))
        self.button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_pressed)

        ### Going to want to setup all the Pub/Sub stuff here
        # Publisher().subscribe(self.updateDisplay, "update")
        pub.subscribe(self.do_action,"action")
        # Going to connect an event to the list box
        pub.subscribe(self.do_update_url,'update_url')
        # Goiong to connect the event 
        pub.subscribe(self.do_sendRequest,'sendRequest')
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle(_("frame_1"))
        self.frame_1_statusbar.SetStatusWidths([-1])
        # statusbar fields
        frame_1_statusbar_fields = [_("status")]
        for i in range(len(frame_1_statusbar_fields)):
            self.frame_1_statusbar.SetStatusText(frame_1_statusbar_fields[i], i)

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(self.combo_box_1, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        sizer_2.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()    

    def button_pressed(self, event):
        print "I was pressed???"
        print "did the action work?"
        # Publisher().sendMessage,"update", recieved
        # pub.sendMessage("action",'lalalalala')
        # wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "update", "Did this work, was I recieved??")
        print self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'action', arg1="ListA", arg2="ListB")
        self.wthread = WorkerThread(self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue)
        self.wthread.dumpFactory()

    def item_selected(self, event):
        self.sendAccessRequest(self.combo_box_1.GetValue())

        # wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage,'action',)

    def do_action(self,arg1=None,arg2=None):
        print "Called from do_action: %s" % (arg1)

    def do_update_url(self,arg1=None, arg2=None):
        print arg1,arg2

        """ Updates the dropdown box """
        self.combo_box_1.Clear()
        for i in arg1:
            self.combo_box_1.Append(i)

    def do_sendRequest(self,arg1=None,arg2=None):
        """ Will get the method sendAccessRequest from EchoClient to send data back and forth """
        self.sendAccessRequest = arg1



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class dump(object):
    """docstring for dump"""
    def __init__(self,obj):
        for attr in dir(obj):
            if hasattr( obj, attr ):
                print( "obj.%s = %s" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
## Threading
class WorkerThread(Thread):
    """ Threading Class """
    def __init__(self,txtbx):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.txtbx = txtbx
        print self.txtbx
        self.start() # Start the thread

    def run(self):
        factory = EchoClientFactory()
        reactor.connectSSL('localhost',8000, factory, CtxFactory())
        reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0)
        self.factory = factory
        self.reactor = reactor

    def dumpFactory(self):
        dump(reactor)




#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# end of class MyFrame
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("app") # replace with the appropriate catalog name

    # app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    app = wx.App()
    # wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: unfortuneatly twisted does not play very well with wx from what I have seen ... see : http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted ... (note thats not to say you cant you just have to implement your own mainloop

Comment: You can run wx under Twisted using the wxreactor and do away with threads. Here is an example wx app that will send and receive information over WebSocket: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/wxpython

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar situation and my solution was to use a Queue that will connect your app with the Thread then you can send messages/commands to the Thread and from the Thread control your server with the data collected, this is a bit of a hustle, I would suggest you putting Twisted on the Qt reactor and using Qt instead of wx, that way you can remove the Thread and make your application of a simpler design !

Hope this can help,
Cheers